# how can I set take profit to double stop loss

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mt4

I am setting up a pending order in the following way in my project:

```
 int ticketSell = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELLLIMIT,lotSize, bottom,0, top,0,"SellOrder",magicnumber,0,Red);
```

How can I make the take profit, double the pips for stop loss? In other words I want a 2:1 win ratio for my pending order.

Also how can I set the entry price which is `bottom` say, 6 pips below `bottom`'s value?

Comment: What is the problem? `double oop=bottom-6*_Point; double osl=top; double slDist=fabs(oop-osl); double otp=oop-2*slDist;` then pass `oop, osl, otp` into the function and that's it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it when the market opens